# Nuts and bolts algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, go, quick-sort

I am trying to learn Golang. 
This is a problem from Robert Sedgewick's *Algorithms* book:

> You have a mixed pile of N nuts and N bolts and need to quickly find
>   the corresponding pairs of nuts and bolts. Each nut matches exactly
>   one bolt, and each bolt matches exactly one nut. By fitting a nut and
>   bolt together, you can see which is bigger. But it is not possible to
>   directly compare two nuts or two bolts. Given an efficient method for
>   solving the problem.

This code applies an algorithm similar to quicksort to solve the problem:

```
// NutsAndBolts.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type nutsBolts struct {
    nuts  []int
    bolts []int
}

type array []int

func newNutsBolts(nuts []int, bolts []int) *nutsBolts {
    nb := new(nutsBolts)
    nb.bolts = bolts
    nb.nuts = nuts
    return nb
}

func (nb *nutsBolts) sort(lo int, hi int) {

    if hi <= lo {
        return
    }
    pivotNut := array(nb.nuts).partition(lo, hi, nb.bolts[lo])
    array(nb.bolts).partition(lo, hi, nb.nuts[pivotNut])

    nb.sort(lo, pivotNut-1)
    nb.sort(pivotNut+1, hi)
}

func (a array) partition(lo int, hi int, pivot int) int {
    i := lo
    j := hi

    var hold int

    for {

        for a[i] < pivot && i < hi {
            i++
        }
        for a[j] > pivot && j > lo {
            j--
        }

        if i >= j {
            break
        }

        hold = a[j]
        a[j] = a[i]
        a[i] = hold

    }

    return j
}

func main() {
    nb := newNutsBolts([]int{5, 8, 4, 3, 1}, []int{3, 5, 4, 1, 8})

    nb.sort(0, len(nb.nuts)-1)

    fmt.Println(nb.nuts)
    fmt.Println(nb.bolts)

}
```

Are there any mistakes with respect to writing good Golang code?

Comment: [Arrays and slices](https://blog.golang.org/slices) are different things in Go. Therefore it's as inadvisable to do `type array []int` as it is to do `type float int`.

Comment: @DaveC can you please advise as to how do I change the program, to use array as a type